# Speed and functionality of dictionary vs list vs array

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, listbox

I'm writing an application in C# using .NET 4.5.  My application reads from and writes to a binary file which is consumed by a hardware device.  The file is exactly 5,000,000 bytes and consists of 100,000 50-byte "blocks".  Each 50 byte block will contain an ASCII-encoded string (possibly just an empty string).  The file layout is required by the device so that any string can be accessed simply by determining the offset (index * 50 bytes and then reading/writing the next 50 bytes).

My WinForms application needs to be able to:

- Load all 100,000 strings from the file and display them in the UI (listbox)
- Add, edit or delete strings
- Re-write the binary file in the proper format

Caveats:

1. A fair amount of the data in the binary file will initially be empty strings that I don't want to display to the user but will still need to be in my data structure so I can re-write the file properly.
2. Before adding a new string, I need to make sure that there's free space to allow it (i.e., at least one 50 byte block that's empty).  If not, then the user will need to "delete" an existing string to make room for the new string to be added.
3. Adding, modifying and deleting strings are, behind the scenes, the same operation.  Adding just changes 50 bytes of null data to 50 bytes of string data while deleting represents the reverse.
4. With the exception of empty strings, duplicate strings shouldn't be stored so I need some way to iterate through my data structure to ensure that a string doesn't already exist before adding it or editing a string to match an existing string.

So I'm going to need a data structure to hold all of the data from the file and I'm struggling to decide between a dictionary, a list or an array.  Given the caveats above, I don't think directly binding any data structure to the UI is a viable solution.  So I *think* that I'm going to need a lot of code between that data structure and the listbox to implement some kind of pseudo-binding.  If that's the case, which data structure (dictionary, list, array, something else) would be the most useful from a functional standpoint and offer the best compromise re: speed with a dataset of this size (100,000 strings of up to 50 ASCII character each)?

Comment: You can probably simply stop at "...100,000 strings ... display them in ...listbox". Usability and performance of this will trump all other costs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with 100,000 entries, I don't think you're going to need to worry too much about performance. (EDIT: I mean, performance when it comes to I/O or alteration of the data. You likely will have issues with your GUI binding)

Program it the simplest way that makes it easiest for you to make changes to your business logic and GUI binding. Perhaps even consider creating your own class that simply wraps a `List` (or `Array` or whatever) with a standard public interface for your GUI that hides this implementation detail.

Once your GUI is running and all your I/O is running fine (and ideally, have some nice suite of unit tests), then you can start benchmarking/profiling and finding where your bottlenecks are.

EDIT: Considering your requirements, this custom/wrapped data structure might be ideal. It can proactively know certain aspects of your data. For example, as it is loaded/read, it can check if space is available for new strings, so when the user goes to add more, you already know if you can. It can maintain a `HashSet` of used unique strings so you have a nice O(1) lookup for duplicate strings, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is critical, best way to figure it out is to test it out. Write a quick-and-dirty app that does the critical stuff all three ways, and then wrap it in a loop that does it all 10,000 times, and see which is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary does not seems necessary here because you don't have any key to index your data.
Lists are good for add/remove items, but this is clearly not needed also.
So I will go for a string array

EDIT: Rethinking about the multiple empty string present, I could suggest a possible optimization if the ratio of empty strings versus filled string is not low.
We could use an array of integer as a map versus a dictionary that contains only the filled string

**Warning: TEST NEEDED**

```
int[] keys = new int[100];  // Just 100 to test the idea
Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();

AddItem(keys, 32, data, "Position 32 34567890123456789012345678901234567890");
AddItem(keys, 40, data, "Position 40 34567890123456789012345678901234567890");
AddItem(keys, 10, data, "Position 10 34567890123456789012345678901234567890");
AddItem(keys, 25, data, "Position 25 34567890123456789012345678901234567890");
AddItem(keys, 99, data, "Position 99 34567890123456789012345678901234567890");
AddItem(keys, 0, data, "Postion 00 234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
AddItem(keys, 18, data, "Position 18 34567890123456789012345678901234567890");

foreach(int x in keys)
{
    if(x == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Empty string");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(data[x]);
}

void AddItem(int[] keys, int keyPos, Dictionary<int, string> data, string message)
{
    int count = data.Count;
    data.Add(count, message);
    keys[keyPos] = count;
}
void RemoveItem(int[] keys, int keyPos, Dictionary<int, string> data)
{
    int x = keys[keyPos];
    data.Remove(x);
    keys[keyPos] = 0;
}
void UpdateItem(int[] keys, int keyPos, Dictionary<int, string> data, string message)
{
    int x = keys[keyPos];
    data[x] = message;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like they might want to key against the string data itself as they do not want to store/use duplicate strings.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, yes I was thinking to leverage the fact of multiple empty string to realize some optimization combining array and dictionary, look at my edit

Comment: Might need to flip it around (or make it bidirectional): if you wanted to see if a string was currently being used, you'd have to do an O(N) iteration through the dictionary values seeing if any of them match.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a dictionary would be the best here to store the data. The key would be the the string being stored, value would be it's location. You can track your free space by the size of the dictionary.

For your listbox, you'd first convert the dictionary to an array, then use the array as the backing store for the listbox. This would be a one time speed penalty you'd pay at the start of the app, but gains you much speed with your UI response and meets the other requirements of the underlying data store.

Add/remove operations are performed on the dictionary which quickly handles checking for duplicates and you can quickly directly update your array should you make changes to the underlying dictionary rather than rebuilding the array.